# CSS transition to appear boxes one by one on mouseover

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I have created a social media box, when you mouseover the share button it will popout and show the social media icons, its working fine right now, but I wanted to have transition on it, so when I mouseover on share button the other 4 items show one by one with some transition effect.

Effect I am looking for is similar to this [site](http://googleplay.flatata.com/), On top right corner.

```css
body {
  background: #cdcdcd;
  padding: 150px 0 0 100px;
}
.social-share {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: #34abd2;
  float: left;
  font-size: 18px;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.social-share > ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.social-share > ul > li {
  list-style: none;
}
.social-share > ul > li > i {
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}
.social-share > ul > li:hover > i {
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.social-share > ul > li > ul {
  line-height: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 35px;
  line-height: normal;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.social-share > ul > li:hover ul {
  visibility: visible;
}
.social-share > ul > li > ul > li {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.social-share > ul > li > ul > li > a {
  color: #fff;
}
.social-share > ul > li > ul > li:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #3C5A99;
}
.social-share > ul > li > ul > li:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #229EF1;
}
.social-share > ul > li > ul > li:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #DD4A40;
}
.social-share > ul > li > ul > li:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: #2FA64A;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="social-share">
  <ul>
    <li><i class="fa fa-share-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I understand the javascript you not satisfied?

Comment: I am actually looking to handle it using CSS only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How is this idea , i think you are looking for this, i have just changed the `overflow:visible` property and add some codes

```css
body {
  background: #cdcdcd;
  padding: 150px 0 0 100px;
}
.social-share {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: #34abd2;
  float: left;
  font-size: 18px;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.social-share:hover {
  overflow:visible;
  transition-duration:1s;
  -moz-transition-duration:1s;
  -ms-transition-duration:1s;
  -webkit-transition-duration:1s;
}
.social-share > ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.social-share > ul > li {
  list-style: none;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.social-share > ul > li > i {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}
.social-share > ul > li:hover > i {
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.social-share > ul > li > ul {
  line-height: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 18px;
  line-height: normal;
  height:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  transition-duration:2s;
  -moz-transition-duration:2s;
  -ms-transition-duration:2s;
  -webkit-transition-duration:2s;
}
.social-share > ul > li:hover ul {
  height:173px;
  transition-duration:2s;
  -moz-transition-duration:2s;
}
.social-share > ul > li > i, .social-share > ul > li > ul > li {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.social-share > ul > li > ul > li > a {
  color: #fff;
}
.social-share > ul > li > ul > li:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #3C5A99;
}
.social-share > ul > li > ul > li:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #229EF1;
}
.social-share > ul > li > ul > li:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #DD4A40;
}
.social-share > ul > li > ul > li:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: #2FA64A;
}
```

```html
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="social-share">
  <ul>
    <li><i class="fa fa-share-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: yes its better, as per the answer of @Adrian Bobrowski it has problem with mouseout

Comment: @JishnuVS can you improve the effect of hiding?

Answer (score 5):

i think `transition-delay` is your answer

```css
body {
  background: #cdcdcd;
  padding: 150px 0 0 100px;
}
.social-share {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: #34abd2;
  float: left;
  font-size: 18px;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.social-share > ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.social-share > ul > li {
  list-style: none;
}
.social-share > ul > li > i {
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}
.social-share > ul > li:hover > i {
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.social-share > ul > li > ul {
  line-height: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 35px;
  line-height: normal;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.social-share > ul > li:hover ul {
  visibility: visible;
}
.social-share > ul > li > ul > li {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.social-share > ul > li > ul > li > a {
  color: #fff;
}
.social-share > ul > li > ul > li:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #3C5A99;
  transition-delay: 0ms;
}
.social-share > ul > li > ul > li:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #229EF1;
  transition-delay: 500ms;
}
.social-share > ul > li > ul > li:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #DD4A40;
  transition-delay: 1000ms;
}
.social-share > ul > li > ul > li:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: #2FA64A;
  transition-delay: 1500ms;
}

.social-share > ul > li:hover > ul > li:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: 1500ms;
}
.social-share > ul > li:hover > ul > li:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: 1000ms;
}
.social-share > ul > li:hover > ul > li:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay: 500ms;
}
.social-share > ul > li:hover > ul > li:nth-child(4) {
  transition-delay: 0ms;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="social-share">
  <ul>
    <li><i class="fa fa-share-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, the way of doing is good idea, I can play with it to adjust it transition timing, thanks!!

Comment: can you fix the hover out order too,

Comment: @JishnuVS I'm sorry I do not understand you. Please expand your request

Comment: i mean when you hover the share , the icons show one by one on bottom,
when hover out hide one by one on the top

Comment: @SanjeevK i improve the effect of hiding and edited my answer. Look. You can also change show/hide effect (fade or other)

Answer (score 3):

According to your question and other answers I think you are looking for the following.

```css
body {
  background: #cdcdcd;
  padding: 150px 0 0 100px;
}

.social-share {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: #34abd2;
  float: left;
  font-size: 18px;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.social-share > ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.social-share > ul > li {
  list-style: none;
}

.social-share > ul > li > i {
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}

.social-share > ul > li:hover > i {
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.social-share > ul > li > ul {
  line-height: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -3px;
  line-height: normal;
  z-index: -1;
}

.social-share > ul > li:hover ul {
  bottom: 35px;
  z-index: auto;
  height: 150px;
}

.social-share > ul > li > ul > li {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 35px;
  left: 0;
  line-height: 35px;
  list-style: outside none none;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
  width: 35px;
}

.social-share > ul > li > ul > li > a {
  color: #fff;
}

.social-share > ul > li > ul > li:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #3C5A99;
}

.social-share > ul > li:hover > ul > li:nth-child(1) {
  bottom: 3px;
}

.social-share > ul > li > ul > li:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #229EF1;
}

.social-share > ul > li:hover > ul > li:nth-child(2) {
  bottom: 41px;
}

.social-share > ul > li > ul > li:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #DD4A40;
}

.social-share > ul > li:hover > ul > li:nth-child(3) {
  bottom: 79px;
}

.social-share > ul > li > ul > li:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: #2FA64A;
}

.social-share > ul > li:hover > ul > li:nth-child(4) {
  bottom: 117px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="social-share">
  <ul>
    <li><i class="fa fa-share-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```